# How can I have lowercase routes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes, case, canonical-link

How can I have lowercase, plus underscore if possible, routes in ASP.NET MVC? So that I would have `/dinners/details/2` call `DinnersController.Details(2)` and, if possible, `/dinners/more_details/2` call `DinnersController.MoreDetails(2)`?

All this while still using patterns like `{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

Comment: I ended up writing all my routes manually anyway for various reasons and I think it's hard to avoid doing that with anything that's not just CRUD. So I just wrote them in lowercase.

Comment: Using **Web Forms**?  Go here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668177.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.  (I am gradually converting my project from web forms to MVC and have both in the project)

Comment: im pretty sure you can do this as default

Comment: i dont think it matters if you type in the routes in lower or upper case.

Answer (score 254):

With System.Web.Routing 4.5 you may implement this straightforward by setting LowercaseUrls  property of RouteCollection:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Also assuming you are doing this for SEO reasons you want to redirect incoming urls to lowercase (as said in many of the links off this article).

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //You don't want to redirect on posts, or images/css/js
        bool isGet = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestType.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("get");
        if (isGet && !HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("."))
        {
            //You don't want to modify URL encoded chars (ex.: %C3%8D that's code to Í accented I) to lowercase, than you need do decode the URL
            string urlLowercase = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
            //You want to consider accented chars in uppercase check
            if (Regex.IsMatch(urlLowercase, @"[A-Z]") || Regex.IsMatch(urlLowercase, @"[ÀÈÌÒÙÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛÃÕÄËÏÖÜÝÑ]"))
            {
                //You don't want to change casing on query strings
                urlLowercase = urlLowercase.ToLower() + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query;

                Response.Clear();
                Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                Response.AddHeader("Location", urlLowercase);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest thing to do in 4.0.

Comment: any way to override on case by case basic for instance upper case SKU or a CamelCase product name?

Comment: Wish this were at the top... Almost cargo-culted a lot of code!

Comment: Great answer :-) The latter SEO part fits nicely into an HTTP module.

Comment: @Aaron Sherman Where is the Application_BeginRequest part supposted to go? It's giving me errors when its inside public class RouteConfig and also when its outside of if.

Comment: @richard-mišenčík add it to Global.asax file

Comment: @ITmeze Thanks, I added it there but now I have just one error: **The name 'Regex' does not exist in the current context**

Comment: @RichardMišenčík, you need to add a using statement for it at the top of your Global.asax file. ("using System.Text.RegularExpressions;")

Comment: @IshmaelSmyrnow Thanks, but I already found that elsewhere so it works now

Comment: Note that this will alter case sensitive URLs on redirect when using `RedirectToRouteResult`, causing potential bugs

Comment: Cheers to Microsoft for this one liner.

Answer (score 44):

These two tutorials helped when I wanted to do the same thing and work well:

http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/03/force-mvc-route-url-lowercase/
http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/

EDIT: For projects with areas, you need to modify the GetVirtualPath() method:

```
public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
  var lowerCaseValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

  foreach (var v in values)
  {
    switch (v.Key.ToUpperInvariant())
    {
      case "ACTION":
      case "AREA":
      case "CONTROLLER":
        lowerCaseValues.Add(v.Key, ((string)v.Value).ToLowerInvariant());
        break;
      default:
        lowerCaseValues.Add(v.Key.ToLowerInvariant(), v.Value);
        break;
    }
  }
  return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, lowerCaseValues);
}
```

Comment: Actually the Wordpress link (@GoNeale's article) is superior.  It provides extension methods for a friendlier registration, and includes handling to redirect incoming requests that aren't in lower case, so that you don't fragment your page ranking in search engines between multiple versions of the same page.

Comment: GONeale link has changed; URL is now http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: Does this still apply to MVC3?

Comment: @Phill Yes the tutorials are still valid.

Comment: @Derek - Nope, the tutorials break down when using Area's. After 3 days of trying EVERYTHING... I found a better solution, theres a library called Attribute Routing. Solves the problem and makes life a lot easier. http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/08/mvc-routing-with-attributes-makes-routing-awesome/

Comment: @Phill I took another look at where I'm using it and sure enough I made a small modification to get it to work with areas in the GetVirtualPath() method.

Comment: This solution doesnot work for me for areas it still works fine for regular case. All my urls in the area section are still not lower case

Comment: sorry, but how and where do you use the Route subclass? Can you please edit the answer to show where to inject this in the asp.net system?

Comment: it has error in some cases. if you add some Object to RouteValue, it cann't cast to string, and it throw exception.

Comment: For mvc 4 there is a better solution using property routes.LowercaseUrls = true; More info on http://www.dhuvelle.com/2012/11/tips-for-aspnet-mvc-4-lowercase-urls.html

Comment: @Marc but does not work for areas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271048/mvc-4-routecollection-lowercaseurls-breaks-when-using-area

Comment: @MarcCals Actually routes.LowercaseUrls comes with .NET 4.5, not MVC 4. Sadly for me.

Comment: @GONeale What happened to your URL? Second link is dead now!  Made me laugh though, the title is "The Best **Gone Ale** Site on the Internet"

Comment: You can read [goneale.com's article here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110310094337/http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/)

Comment: @chteuchteu that link didn't work for me, but [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20131228221926/http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/) did.

Answer (score 33):

If you happened to use ASP.NET Core, you probably should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39113342/1414809):

> Add the following line to the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class.
>
> ```
> services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
> ```

Comment: Same for Core 2.0.  Also at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777372/195755

Answer (score 21):

If you are using the UrlHelper to generate the link, you can simply specify the name of the action and controller as lowercase:

```
itemDelete.NavigateUrl = Url.Action("delete", "photos", new { key = item.Key });
```

Results in: /media/photos/delete/64 (even though my controller and action are pascal case).

Comment: I think doing this work in one central location is the easiest and most standard solution. This is just as bad as inline CSS. (Apparently 15 people use inline CSS).

Comment: Is it true for Linux servers too?

Answer (score 16):

I found this at [Nick Berardi’s Coder Journal](http://www.coderjournal.com/2008/03/force-mvc-route-url-lowercase/), but it did not have information on how to implement the `LowercaseRoute` class.  Hence reposting here with additional information.

First extend the `Route` class to `LowercaseRoute`

```
public class LowercaseRoute : Route
{
    public LowercaseRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, routeHandler) { }
    public LowercaseRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, defaults, routeHandler) { }
    public LowercaseRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, defaults, constraints, routeHandler) { }
    public LowercaseRoute(string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, RouteValueDictionary constraints, RouteValueDictionary dataTokens, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, defaults, constraints, dataTokens, routeHandler) { }
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        VirtualPathData path = base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);

        if (path != null)
            path.VirtualPath = path.VirtualPath.ToLowerInvariant();

        return path;
    }
}
```

Then modify the `RegisterRoutes` method of Global.asax.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.Add(new LowercaseRoute("{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }), 
        new MvcRouteHandler()));

    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    "Default",                                              // Route name
    //    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    //    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    //);
}
```

I would however like to know a way to use routes.MapRoute...

Comment: GONeale's article provides an extension method so you can write `routes.MapRouteLowercase(...` which is nicer than the above: http://goneale.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: GONeale's entire blog disappeared. [Here is another blog entry](http://blog.dantup.com/2009/04/reducing-duplicate-content-with-aspnet.html) with similar content (and the same extension method). It addresses this situation in the context of reducing duplicate content.

Answer (score 11):

You can continue use the MapRoute syntax by adding this class as an extension to RouteCollection:

```
public static class RouteCollectionExtension
{
    public static Route MapRouteLowerCase(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults)
    {
        return routes.MapRouteLowerCase(name, url, defaults, null);
    }

    public static Route MapRouteLowerCase(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url, object defaults, object constraints)
    {
        Route route = new LowercaseRoute(url, new MvcRouteHandler())
        {
            Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary(defaults),
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(constraints)
        };

        routes.Add(name, route);

        return route;
    }
}
```

Now you can use in your application's startup "MapRouteLowerCase" instead of "MapRoute":

```
    public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Url shortcuts
        routes.MapRouteLowerCase("Home", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        routes.MapRouteLowerCase("Login", "login", new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
        routes.MapRouteLowerCase("Logout", "logout", new { controller = "Account", action = "Logout" });

        routes.MapRouteLowerCase(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

Comment: For anyone reading this, the `LowercaseRoute` class in the first code snippet above appears to come from [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/931764/1822514)

Answer (score 5):

This actually has two answers:

1. You can already do this: the route engine does case-insensitive comparison.  If you type a lower-case route, it will be routed to the appropriate controller and action.
2. If you are using controls that generate route links (ActionLink, RouteLink, etc.) they will produce mixed-case links unless you override this default behavior.

You're on your own for the underscores, though...

Answer (score 3):

Could you use the ActionName attribute?

```
 [ActionName("more_details")]
 public ActionResult MoreDetails(int? page)
 {

 }
```

I don't think case matters. More_Details, more_DETAILS, mOrE_DeTaILs in the URL all take you to the same Controller Action.

Comment: I haven't tried that - will it let you use either one?  ("moredetails" or "more_details")

Comment: To follow up, I tried it and it requires you to use the specified name, so no, it won't allow you to handle it either way.  Also, depending how you constructed your controller action and view, you may need to specify the name of the view explicitly.