# ASP.NET MVC: Get lowercase links (instead of Camel Case)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-links

All my dynamically generated action links etc. are creating links like /**A**ccount/**S**etup. It looks strange.

I'd like all my links to be lowercase (meaning /account/setup). Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/.  You can find more information in another stackoverflow at [How can I have lowercase routes in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc).

The other posts thus far have not tackled the scenario where you navigate to the root of your web directory.  If you have a mapping that directs to the HomeController Index action, you would like the following URL to appear:

`mysite/home/` or even `mysite/home/index`

No amount of Html helper function usage will change the fact that, by default, the following will be shown in the browser location bar:

`mysite/Home` or `mysite/Home/Index`

Answer (score 6):

There is simpler solution in .NET Framework 4.5, a new property **RouteCollection.LowercaseUrls**, here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12055932/472126)

Answer (score 0):

Write an extension method for Html:

```
public static class MyHtmlExtensions
{
    public static string LowerActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,someargs)
    {
        return String.ToLowerInvariant(htmlHelper.ActionLink(someArgs));
    }
}
```

Then use Html.LowerActionLink instead of Html.ActionLink

Comment: Are the routes not case sensitive, then?

Comment: I think not, otherwise I'm in big trouble.

Comment: Ah... perhaps you might want to preserve some case in the later parts of the route. More judicious use of ToLower in the extension method might be advised

Comment: Scratch all of that. In all but the simplest of cases, I don't think doing this is such a good idea, but am leaving it up in case it fits OPs needs.