# How to route lower-case URLs ('questions/add_to_favorites/123') with underscores in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-routing

ASP.NET MVC 2 controllers and actions use UpperCamelCase.

For some reasons many big sites, including SO, use lowercase (with underscore) for controllers and actions in the urls. Examples:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
https://stackoverflow.com/users/377920/randomguy
http://www.reddit.com/ad_inq/
http://www.wired.com/special_multimedia/mobile/
etc.
```

I would like to know how this is accomplished.

The default router seems to be case-insensitive, ie. `stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` will be directed to Questions-controller's Ask() method without a problem.

However, say we want to direct `questions/add_to_favorites` to Questions-controller's AddToFavorites() action.

1. How is this accomplished?
2. Is it now required to use `Html.ActionLink("add_to_favorites")`
   instead of `Html.ActionLink("AddToFavorites")` to make the links in the HTML point as `questions/add_to_favorites` instead of `Questions/AddToFavorites`?

---

Edit:
Similar posts

- [How can I have lowercase routes in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [ASP.NET MVC: Get lowercase links (instead of Camel Case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417389/asp-net-mvc-get-lowercase-links-instead-of-camel-case)

One way to support underscores is to use the ActionName attribute:

```
[ActionName("add_to_favorites")]
public ActionResult AddToFavorites() {
  // ...
}
```

However, this doesn't work for controllers. Perhaps if we could somehow remove all the underscores from the request before it gets to the routing mechanism, then it would work.

Comment: Quick side note. Please ensure that `add_to_favorite` requires POST. GET request should never modify state on the server

Comment: Agreed! This is seriously not only for RESTful purists: state changing GET requests create security holes. Although, if you force authorization and prevent cross-site request forgery (using AntiForgeryToken), I don't think GET'ing is a problem technically speaking.

Comment: And please note that simply adding [HttpPost] won't solve the security issues; the bad guy could simply emulate a form post. So even though you are forcing POSTs (or DELETEs/PUTs from AJAX), you still have be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom routes manually. This is not an universal solution and must be added for every controller and action separately.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Web2.0 RoR style lowercase URLs with underscores", 
    "questions-foo/add_to_favorites", 
    new { controller = "Questions", action = "AddToFavorites" }
);
```

The cool thing is that the URL generating Html-helper methods don't need to be modified. The routing table is used to route incoming requests *and* to generate URLs. So,

`Html.ActionLink("Add to favorites", "Questions", "AddToFavorites");` maps to `/questions-foo/add_to_favorites`.

Note that the original `/Question/AddToFavorites` still works as does `/qUeStIoN/aDdtOfAvOrItEs` as well as `/qUeStIoNs-FOO/ADD_TO_FAVORITES` because the default routing mechanism is case-insensitive.