# How can I specify the name of the controller in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have an ApiController, quite simple, like this:

```cs
public class AssetController : ApiController
{
// removed for brevity
}
```

When I insert a route to it from a view, the url created is something like:

```
http://host/Asset
```

but I would like to customize the name, so that it becomes this:

```
http://host/assets
```

How can I specify a custom name for my controller, without resorting to a complete custom routing table?

Comment: For making it lowercase... have you checked out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168270/making-url-lowercase-any-easy-or-builtin-way ?

They tend to point to a CodePlex project here  http://lowercaseroutesmvc.codeplex.com/ check out section: (Step 4. (if using ASP.NET Web API) - Remap Your HTTP)

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at that, and I've been going through the source code but I can't find anything that helps me. I think the only way forward today is a custom routetable.

Comment: I've updated the question body to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to resolve this issue so I've opted to adjust my routing table to reflect the API that I really want.

Answer (score 1):

> When I insert a route to it from a view, the url created is something like: `http://host/Asset`

You haven't really shown how you are doing this *inserting* but the following should work fine:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "false", controller = "assets" })
```

and if you want an absolute url you could specify the protocol scheme as third argument:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "false", controller = "assets" }, "http")
```

And in order to obey RESTFul conventions you should rename your controller to `AssetsController`.

Comment: Someone helpful, thank you. It does make me rename my controller to influence the name. I'm trying to get the RESTFul convention of having a plural name, but I don't see how that's supposed to be the controller's concern.

Comment: It's the controller's concern in terms of conventions. That's how ASP.NET MVC routing works. So follow those conventions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting library. It handles this aspect quite well by putting an attribute right on each function and giving it a specific route (which can be anything).