# "routes.LowercaseUrls = true;" does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I'm having trouble in setting my routes to lowercase by default. For some reason it does not work. I know I can set `authorize` and `home` to lowercase myself, but the `Admin` part (area) will still be capitalized..

`@Html.ActionLink("Hello World", "Authorize", "Home")`

outputs to

`<a href="/Admin/Home/Authorize">Hello World</a>`

Area route

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "OR.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
            context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        }
```

Default route

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Localization",
                url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "OR.Controllers" }
            );
            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new string[] { "OR.Controllers" }
            );

            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        }
```

### Admin Area configs I tried

```
// admin/Home/Authorize
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { area = "admin", controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "ORMebeles.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
    context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
}

// admin/Home/Authorize
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "ORMebeles.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
    context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
}
```

### Edit

As it seems this is bug with MVC4 - when you set `context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` and you have Area/Areas `context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` won't take any effect, where should we report it or how can we get it fixed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET 4.5 MVC RouteCollection.LowercaseUrls breaks when using Area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271048/net-4-5-mvc-routecollection-lowercaseurls-breaks-when-using-area)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is bug related to MVC4 and will be fixed in MVC5 release. `Routes.LowercaseUrls` does not affect areas. More info [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/685).

Meanwhile you can use [LowercaseRoutesMVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseRoutesMVC/1.0.3) or 
[LowercaseRoutesMVC4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LowercaseRoutesMVC/1.0.3) if you need WebApi support.

Answer (score 1):

I tried ***Several*** attempts to get this particular boolean flag to work with an MVC3 project with no luck.  The ***ONLY*** way I could get it to work was to create an MVC4 application project and set the flag in the RouteConfig.cs file in the app start.  **The really bad part** is it lowercased the urls across the site automatically for me until I added an area, then it broke everywhere.  Once I excluded the newly added area from the project and reran, the urls were lowercased again.

Something is wonkey with the use of that flag.  I would recommend downloading the nuget package for lowercasing urls.  It seems as if they haven't quite worked out the kinks in this part of the new framework.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I know of this post, but since I'm using .NET 4.5 that has `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` it should work. I'm asking why it's not working.

Comment: What IIS version are you running?

Comment: Check to see if you are running the IIS Url Rewrite module and if it's overriding this behavior

Comment: Also, is the lowercasing working on standard routes and just not with Area routes?

Comment: It seems this may be a bug in the .net code.  After decompiling the route namespace and looking at the NormalizeVirtualPath function it seems like it may miss that portion of the url when it gets the DataTokens from the RoutesCollection.  Can't tell for sure without completely recreating and debugging into the .net libraries but you don't seem to be the only one having this issue when it comes to areas.

Comment: if you lowercase the word Admin in the registration of your area routes, do the rest of the url tokens lowercase for the controller and action?  if so that would confirm that the code related to that flag is missing the area portion of the url when it does the ToLowerInvariant in the .net code.

Comment: try including the area in with the datatokens
    routes.MapRoute(
         "Default",
         "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { area = "YourArea", controller = "home", action =     "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

Comment: Did any of that work?  I'm very curious about this now and may try to duplicate this weekend to look into it.

Comment: No, none of it worked. I added admin area code for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: ***IN AN MVC4 application***

Create a new blank MVC4 application and add an Area Called Test, with a Test.cshtml View and a TestController.cs controller.

So I figured out something... though I am not sure if it's a reasonable solution.  After playing with the route registration routines, having the areas in the project doesn't break the lowercase functionality.

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Areas.Test
{
public class TestAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Test";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        //This line breaks the functionality in the area registration.
        context.MapRoute(
            "Test_default", // Route name
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = "" }, // Parameter defaults
            new string[] { "MvcApplication1.Areas.Test.Controllers" } //namespace
            );
    }
}
}
```

A workaround:

Comment out the lines

```
        //context.Routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        //context.MapRoute(
        //    "Test_default", // Route name
        //    "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        //    new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = "" }, // Parameter defaults
        //    new string[] { "MvcApplication1.Areas.Test.Controllers" } //namespace
        //    );
```

In RouteConfig.cs

```
namespace MvcApplication1
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Test_default", // Route name
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Test", action = "Index", id = "" }, // Parameter defaults
            new string[] { "MvcApplication1.Areas.Test.Controllers" } //namespace
            );
    }
}
}
```

In The Area Controller Action Method

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Key if statement to make sure the area maps correctly
        if (!this.ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area"))
        {
            this.ControllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("area", "Test");
        }
        return View("Test");
    }
```

Resulting HTML for the links in the main page of the project

```
 <ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/home/about">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="/home/contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li><a href="/test?area=Test">Test</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Notice however the query string variables are not lowercased and it is not an seo friendly url.  However it does find the view.  This is as close as I've been able to come using that flag and having the urls go to lowercase.

Comment: Well this is somewhat solution but nobody would like their urls to look like `/test?area=Test` in 2012.

Answer (score -1):

As I known, `LowercaseUrls = true` is only available in .NET4.5, maybe you can just write some extensions for lowercase urls. you can refer to [making URL lowercase. Any easy or builtin way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168270/making-url-lowercase-any-easy-or-builtin-way) for detail info.

Comment: I use MVC4 with .NET 4.5. This is not the issue.