# mvc lowercase route (error im getting is "RouteCollection is a nested class"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

so i know there's this 2 main links talking about lowering the cases for the urls, here they are respectively:

[How can I have lowercase routes in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/3035418#3035418)

http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/

anyway, they're basically identical but my problem is on the RouteCollectionExtensions class that has a MapLowercaseRoute method. It's giving me a "Extension method must be defined ina top level static class; RouteCollectionExtensions is a nested class."

which kind of makes sense cuz it's just looping around but I basically used the same codes on that 2nd link..
any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `RouteCollectionExtensions` class into a separate `.cs` file, don't nest it inside some existing class.