# .net MVC3 Lowercase route URLs in areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/

That helped me with a great solution to get lowercase urls in my site, but it doesnt work with AREAS. Any one have a similar elegant solution for lowercase Urls for areas??

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the top answer to another question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: thanks .. the top answer didnt work for me though