# RouteData.Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() Indeed return the current controller name but it return it as the user type it.

For example, my app contains "ImageGallery" controller and if the user type `http://localhost/imagegallery` to get it - then I get "imagegallery" from the RouteData.Values instead of "ImageGallery".

How can I get the original controller name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can get the actual CLR instance of your controller, and get the name from there on your view...

```
@if (this.ViewContext.Controller is MyController)
{
}
```

and perhaps strip the "Controller" part of it's name... like

```
this.ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Name.Replace("Controller", "")
```

PS: Used `.Replace(string, string)` for the sake of simplicity of this post, but it's probably better to use a `.Substring(int, int)` call.

**EDIT:** You can also get the current controller from the Controller context if you were not in a View (though you'd be in the controller, in which case `this.GetType()` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

You get what the user entered because it does not matter typically ([unless you are Linux/Unix](http://www.wisegeek.com/are-urls-case-sensitive.htm)). However, if your problem deals with the routes not resolving properly, then maybe [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc) is what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to translate it from my Resource file and it's case-sensitive.

Comment: I do not believe that you can change this as you get whatever the user entered. The best suggestion I have seen is to use a regex to deal with the case, otherwise.