# Web Api - How to automatically transform to lowercase url parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following configured route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("oneKey",
                    "{controller}/{id}");
```

If I go to the endpoint `/users/Maticicero`, the route will be correctly delegated to the `GET` method in my `UsersController` class.

However I am getting the `id` parameter just as it was typed, like `Maticicero`.
Since this is the primary key of my database, and the comparision is case sensitive, I need to normalize my ids to lowercase, that is:

```
id = id.ToLower()
```

I have to do this in every controller and in every method that takes the `id` parameter.

Is there a way to tell my Web Api (or route handler) to automatically lower case these parameters (or the whole url)?

Comment: @naveen That's a Route Constraint. It won't modify the value, it will just fail to match the route if it's not lower case. This isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: yep. still sleepy i guess. deleting comment :)

Comment: Why not use a Primary Key that can't be confused in lookups. E.g an INT or GUID. And if you ever need to search on name use `Name LIKE '%name%'`

Comment: @Xenolightning We're currently using AWS `DynamoDB` as our persistence strategy. While having an int key was feasible, the server would be responsible for generating the associated ids (because DynamoDB does not support auto incremental keys), this would make us create a GUID for each user, those messing up the URL. We chose the username as the primary key instead for this reason (it also complies with the requirement that the username must be unique)

Comment: @MatiCicero Are you querying the DynamoDb directly from you controllers? If so, you may want to look at using repositories over your data access. It would allow you to implement consistent logic for your Db queries. `Controller -> UserRepository (call ToLower here) -> DynamoDb`. Relying solely on WebApi to give you the correct case of a string is very fragile code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` when you register your routes. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.lowercaseurls(v=vs.110).aspx)

> *RouteCollection.LowercaseUrls*:
>   Gets or sets a value that indicates whether URLs are converted to
>   lower case when virtual paths are normalized.

But be careful when you use your requests like this `http://host/controller?id=Maticicero`

> If a query string is included in the URL, that part of the URL is not
>   converted to lower case.

Also take a look at this SO question: [How can I have lowercase routes in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878578/how-can-i-have-lowercase-routes-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using ASP.NET Web Api and not MVC, so I am given a `HttpRouteCollections` instead of the `RouteCollections` you mention. That class does not have this property :(

Answer (score 0):

You can trap the URL in the `Application_BeginRequest` event, parse the URL, and use `HttpContext.RewritePath` to modify the original URL.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Going to try this today and keep you informed!