# How do you enforce lowercase routing in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

In ASP.NET 4 this was as easy as `routes.LowercaseUrls = true;` in the `RegisterRoutes` handler for the app.

I cannot find an equivalent in ASP.NET Core for achieving this. I'd think it would be here:

```
app.UseMvc(configureRoutes =>
{
    configureRoutes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller=App}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

But nothing in `configureRoutes` looks to allow it... unless there's an extension method somewhere that I can't find in the docs perhaps?

Answer (score 338, accepted):

For ASP.NET Core:

Add one of the following lines to the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

or

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

Thanks to Skorunka for the answer as a comment. I thought it was worth promoting to an actual answer.

Comment: It's worth noting you should put this BEFORE you actually call `AddMvc()` in your `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method. `AddRouting()` which is also called by `AddMvc()`uses the `Try` variants of the methods for adding dependencies to your service collection. So when it sees that the routing dependencies have already been added, it will skip that parts of `AddMvc()` setup logic.

Comment: Switching this to correct answer since mine was during the transition of asp 4 to core.

Comment: @NickAlbrecht it doesn't seem to make a difference if it's called before or after (as of ASP.NET Core 5.0, at least). AddRouting() will be called twice anyway, so it doesn't matter in which order.

Comment: I believe that was done around .NET Core 3.x. They changed it so that routing was a stand alone feature instead of bundled with MVC. I don't believe routing is called from the `AddMvc` (or `AddControllersWithViews` if you don't need RazorPages) anymore. So the order only really matters if you're using AspNetCore 2. (Don't recall if this was an option in 1.x). However they *did* split the lowercase behavior into two settings, so if you want fully lower case addresses, you need to set both `LowercaseUrls` and `LowercaseQueryStrings` to `true`.

Comment: Can you clarify that the 2nd option is for Razor Pages and first for MVC?

Comment: although this will generate lowercase urls, it **will not enforce** lowercase urls. you can still enter urls with uppercase characters. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631028/1097123) for how to enforce lowercase urls by rewriting any uppercase urls to lowercase.

Answer (score 73):

### Update in ASP.NET Core Version >= 2.2

From **ASP.NET Core 2.2**, along with **lowercase** you can also make your **route dashed** using `ConstraintMap` which will make your route `/Employee/EmployeeDetails/1` to `/employee/employee-details/1` instead of `/employee/employeedetails/1`.

To do so, first create the `SlugifyParameterTransformer` class should be as follows:

```
public class SlugifyParameterTransformer : IOutboundParameterTransformer
{
    public string TransformOutbound(object value)
    {
        // Slugify value
        return value == null ? null : Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1-$2").ToLower();
    }
}
```

**For ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC:**

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddRouting(option =>
{
    option.ConstraintMap["slugify"] = typeof(SlugifyParameterTransformer);
});
```

And Route configuration should be as follows:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller:slugify}/{action:slugify}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

**For ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API:**

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options => 
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}
```

**For ASP.NET Core >=3.0 MVC:**

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddRouting(option =>
{
    option.ConstraintMap["slugify"] = typeof(SlugifyParameterTransformer);
});
```

And Route configuration should be as follows:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
      endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
          name: "AdminAreaRoute",
          areaName: "Admin",
          pattern: "admin/{controller:slugify=Dashboard}/{action:slugify=Index}/{id:slugify?}");

      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
          name: "default",
          pattern: "{controller:slugify}/{action:slugify}/{id:slugify?}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

**For ASP.NET Core >=3.0 Web API:**

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddControllers(options => 
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new RouteTokenTransformerConvention(new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
});
```

**For ASP.NET Core >=3.0 Razor Pages:**

In the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options => 
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new PageRouteTransformerConvention(new SlugifyParameterTransformer()));
})
```

This is will make `/Employee/EmployeeDetails/1` route to `/employee/employee-details/1`

Comment: I tried this code and official Microsoft code too, but "slugify" parameter transformer has no effect. It is just ignored by routing system (so URLs not replaced to dashed ones). To check myself i put logger into TransformOutbound() method, but no calls from there.

Comment: Okay! Let me check please!

Comment: @user3172616 I have check it right now! its working as expected! like generating route as `employee-details`. Would you show me your configuration please?

Comment: @user3172616 are you using attribute routing on the route that you tested?

Comment: I use standard routing approach (not attribute routing) on brand new core v2.2 solution in Visual Studio. There are two screenshots (c# code and .cshtml code). I tried to generate links in different ways with no effect.
https://imgur.com/a/L8dCF6c

Comment: Found nothing wrong in your code! Would give a try removing `SlugifyParameterTransformer` class from `startup` class to anywhere?

Comment: I moved SlugifyParameterTransformer to separate *.cs file with no success. Generated urls are still the same like "/home/thisisthetest". Also i tried to throw random exception from there, it has no effect. But if i comment code line where i register this Transformer then app crashes because it uses unknown "slugify" placeholder in the route as expected.

Comment: Sorry to hear that! Don't know what wrong happening in case of you while its working fine in my application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186496/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-user3172616).

Answer (score 27):

As other answers indicate, adding:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

before

```
services.AddMvc(...)
```

works great, but I also want to add that if you use Identity, you will also need:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    var appCookie = options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie;
    appCookie.LoginPath = appCookie.LoginPath.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
    appCookie.LogoutPath = appCookie.LogoutPath.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
    appCookie.ReturnUrlParameter = appCookie.ReturnUrlParameter.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
});
```

And obviously, replace both `IdentityUser`, and `IdentityRole` with your own classes if required.

I just tested this with .NET Core SDK 1.0.4 and the 1.0.5 runtime.

Comment: Configure<RouteOptions>() is the best answer imho: tiny and straight to the point (tested on mvc core 3.1)

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution.

In the assembly: `Microsoft.AspNet.Routing`, and the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace, you can do this in your `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method:

```
services.ConfigureRouting(setupAction =>
{
    setupAction.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```

Comment: For ASP NET MVC CORE:

   services.AddRouting(options =>
   {
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
   });

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll

Comment: This was true before RTM, now you should use .AddRouting in stead of .ConfigureRouting

Answer (score 10):

It is worth noting that setting:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

**does not affect query strings**.

To ensure that query strings are also lowercase, set the `options.LowercaseQueryStrings` to `true`:

```
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => 
{ 
    options.LowercaseUrls = true; 
    options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
});
```

However, setting this property to `true` is only relevant if `options.LowercaseUrls` is also `true`. `options.LowercaseQueryStrings` property is ignored if `options.LowercaseUrls` is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

For identity, [@Jorge Yanes Diez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44202824/3367974) answer doesn't work in `ASP.NET Core 2.2` (*I think 2.x*), so if you use Identity and ASP.NET Core 2.2 (2.x) here is the solution:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = "returnurl";
    ...
});
```

Ref: [Configure ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#cookie-settings)

Answer (score -1):

I had this on RegisterRoutes::RouteConfig:

routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

Comment: It's for asp.net mvc 5