# ASP.NET Core RazorPages to force AnchorTagHelper (asp-page) to use lowercase routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, razor-pages

I am using RazorPages in ASP.NET Core v2.0, and I was wondering if anyone knows how to force the `AnchorTagHelper` to use lowercase?

For example, in my `.cshtml` mark-up, I would have the following anchor tag using the `asp-page` tag helper:

```
<a asp-page="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
```

The output that I am looking for

```
// i want this 
<a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>

// i get this 
<a href="/Contact-us">Contact Us</a>
```

To give it more context to why this is important to my web app, please imagine a long url like what you would see at stackoverflow.com

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/anchortaghelper-asp-page-to-use-lowercase

                       -- VS --

https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/Anchortaghelper-asp-page-to-use-lowercase
```

Any help would be appreciated!

---

I have looked at these other references but no luck:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6393
- [How do you enforce lowercase routing in ASP.NET Core MVC 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36358751/3645638)

Comment: Did you set that setting your links suggest you to set?

Comment: Since the tag-helpers are just syntactic sugar why not just write out the href directly? The asp.net custom is to PascalCase page names

Comment: @BradPatton You might have a point, but there are features of `asp-page` such as proper handling for "un-routable" non-existent page links. -- I totally agree with the pascal case point too, the file structure gets ugly by doing what I did in my answer below.

Comment: How did you set `LowercaseUrls`? Because I just created a new web app with razor pages and it worked just fine.

Comment: I used the taghelper `<a asp-page="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>` and the output was `<a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>`.

Comment: No it is `Contact-Us.cshtml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url helper that will generate the target link will use the metadata that is being generated for routes. For razor pages, this uses the exact file path to identify the route.

Starting with ASP.NET Core 2.1, you will likely be able to adjust the route just like MVC routes using the `Route` attribute. At least [it’s planned for the 2.1 release](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6605).

Until then, you will have to configure specific routes for your pages in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/ContactUs", "contact-us");
    });
```

---

This will keep the existing route available for use, so if you do not want that, you will need to *replace* the route selector for this page. There is no built-in way to do this, but it’s not too difficult to do it when you know what to do.

To avoid code duplication and to make everything nicer, we’ll just create a `ReplacePageRoute` extension method, that basically matches the usage of the `AddPageRoute` above:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options => {
        options.Conventions.ReplacePageRoute("/Contact", "contact-us");
    });
```

The implementation of that method is directly inspired by that [`AddPageRoute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/DependencyInjection/PageConventionCollectionExtensions.cs#L185):

```
public static PageConventionCollection ReplacePageRoute(this PageConventionCollection conventions, string pageName, string route)
{
    if (conventions == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(conventions));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pageName));
    if (route == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(route));

    conventions.AddPageRouteModelConvention(pageName, model =>
    {
        // clear all existing selectors
        model.Selectors.Clear();

        // add a single selector for the new route
        model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
        {
            AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
            {
                Template = route,
            }
        });
    });

    return conventions;
}
```

Comment: I like this one much more than my solution, with one big exception... I believe that `/ContactUs` would still be route-able in your example. How can you remove the default route?

Comment: @Svek Expanded my answer for that

Answer (score 19):

Add the following to your `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`. It can be added before or after `services.AddMvc();`

```
services.AddRouting(options =>
{
    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});
```

Now for the anchor tag

```
<a asp-page="/Contact-Us">Contact Page</a>
```

And the output

```
<a href="/contact-us">Contact Page</a>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. See http://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper#routing-options

Answer (score 7):

It's a bit easier now, simply add this to your ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs.

```
 services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.LowercaseUrls = true;
                });
```

Comment: This is a very simple solution. Thank you.