# How to enforce lowercase routes in .NET 6?

Tags: .net-6.0

I would like to enforce lowercase routes in .NET 6 API project.

Here is my `Program.cs`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is my `WeatherForecastController.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Weather.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("weatherforecast")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I expect only the lowercase route (https://localhost:7243/weatherforecast) to work, but the route w/ pascal/uppercase works as well (https://localhost:7243/Weatherforecast)

I thought I can add `builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);` and `app.UseRouting()`, but I'm still able to access the route with pascal/uppercase: https://localhost:7243/Weatherforecast.

Here is the modified `Program.cs` file that I tried, but doesn't work:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: question here is actually *why* would you want to enforce case-sensitive routes? (unless you want to use base64 stuff - which would lead to a myriad of other questions)

Comment: also see this answer on SE: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/why-are-urls-case-sensitive

Comment: my reason to enforce case-sensitive routes is for stricter enforcement of routes to prevent case-insensitive routes. I want to enforce (api/weatherforecast) but not (Api/Weatherforecast or API/WEATHERFORECAST etc)

Comment: that's not actually a reason and - if you read the SE answer - not really applicable either - I can understand you want it, but reason why it's important

Comment: what I meant: there should be NO case sensitive route according to the specs

Comment: @riffnl The reason it's important for routes to be case sensitive is that /somePage and /somepage are considered two different endpoints by google and if you have offsite links to both google will flag one of the urls as being duplicate content and also your google SEO juice will be diluted between the various casings of the url.

Comment: One solution is to setup a redirect rule. You may find this SO question and answers useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469342/redirect-asp-net-core-2-0-urls-to-lowercase

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To generate lowercase URLs, add the following to **Program.cs**.
(Note: this does not enforce lowercase URLs).

```cs
// generate lowercase URLs
builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
   options.LowercaseUrls = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();
```

To enforce lowercase URLs, create an IRule-based rule that will redirect any uppercase URLs to lowercase URLs.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50631028/18644913) stackoverflow answer and [IRule-based rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting#irule-based-rule) documentation.

Once you created an IRule-based rule (i.e., `RedirectLowerCaseRule`), add the following to **Program.cs**:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();

// enforce lowercase URLs
// by redirecting uppercase urls to lowercase urls
var options = new RewriteOptions().Add(new RedirectLowerCaseRule());
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: simple, concise answer. Thank you!