# How to force all URLs to lowercase in ASP.NET Core 2.2 and newer version?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-5.0

I want to convert all URLs to lowercase.

For example:

- `https://ABC123.com/` -> `https://abc123.com/`
- `https://StackoverFlow.com/` -> `https://stackoverflow.com/`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `string yourUrl = "https://ABC123.com"; string lowercaseUrl = yourUrl.ToLower();` - wouldn't that work?

Comment: I have to apply this runtime, I am not sure what is the best solution as I have to add in startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to force all URL to lowercase in browser? If it is, You can add

```
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

in your startup.cs class.

[image]

Comment: If the user types a capital URL and I want to redirect them to lowercase, then it will not be helpful.

Comment: Sry i don't get your point, in this case, even user type a capital url, url will also match lowercase.

Comment: I found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469342/redirect-asp-net-core-2-0-urls-to-lowercase/50631028#50631028

Thank you for your try