# Is it possible to make the URL on the webpage lowercase?

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make the url to be small but it doesn't work

```
  string AbsoluteUrl = Context.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLowerInvariant();
      string lowerCaseAbsoluteUrl = AbsoluteUrl.ToLowerInvariant();

      //string Path = builder.Path.ToLowerInvariant();
      UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(AbsoluteUrl);
      string constructedUri = builder.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();


      builder.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
```

i can make it to lower case but can't force the lower case url to be the one is renderd on the website so i tried to make a redirect after i make it to lower cases

```
 //Check if the URL is not already in lowercase
 if (!AbsoluteUrl.Equals(AbsoluteUrl.ToLowerInvariant()))
 {
     Convert the URL to lowercase
     string lowerCaseAbsoluteUrl = AbsoluteUrl.ToLowerInvariant();

     Redirect to the lowercase URL

 Response.RedirectPermanent(lowerCaseAbsoluteUrl);
     UriBuilder builderlower = new UriBuilder(lowerCaseAbsoluteUrl);
 }
```

but the website broke down to too many redirections

Comment: Maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469342/redirect-asp-net-core-2-0-urls-to-lowercase. The main idea is that you redirect only, if original url has upper case characters to avoid infinite redirect

Comment: the if condition should be doing that that the redirect only can happen if there is an upper case

Comment: Can you debug this, to find out the value of AbsoluteUrl after one redirect? It is *supposed* to be lowercase, but why doesn't it match the lowercase version?

Comment: Nitpick: you are executing AbsoluteUrl.ToLowerInvariant() twice

Comment: when i debug it goes fine till i redirect it redirect correctly to the lower case but then it goes back to Application_start and start the operation over and over again and in web page it crashes and gives me arror too-many-redirects

Comment: After the first (or second..) redirect, apparently the condition in `if (!AbsoluteUrl.Equals(AbsoluteUrl.ToLowerInvariant()))` is still true when you expect it to be false. What *is* the value of `AbsoluteUrl` then and why isn't it lowercase? Is maybe somewhere else forcing some part to uppercase (just guessing here)?